# Using jquery with file upload form field

Tags: jquery, html, forms

I'm not sure this is possible without some kind of server interaction but I am hoping it is for prototyping purposes. I have a file upload form field. I would like user to be able to select image from hard drive and jquery will put that image into a div in the DOM.

Here is my code

```
<div class="label">Upload Your Own Logo</div>
  <input name="upload" type="file" id="logo-upload">
```

Div where image should go

```
<div class="user-logo">logo.png</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need AJAX for that. In fact you don't even need jquery.

```
<input type="file" name="ss" id="fileUpload" onchange="dothis()"/>
<div id="picDiv"></div>
```

use function dothis() to append the image you upload inside #picDiv

```
function dothis()
{
    var oImg=document.createElement("img");
    oImg.setAttribute('src', document.getElementById("fileUpload").value);
    oImg.setAttribute('alt', 'na');
    document.getElementById("picDiv").appendChild(oImg);
}
```

Don't forget to check if the file is valid image or not, which I leave it upto you.

Comment: I am getting a 404 on the image.     "NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://localhost:8080/Logo4U/cropped.jpg"  is there a reason why it's looking for the image in the root folder?

Comment: what browser are you targeting?

Comment: All of them, but was initially testing in FF

Answer (score 1):

If the user's browser has HTML5 FileReader API then this is possible:

```
var file = document.getElementById('logo-upload').files[0],
    reader = new FileReader();
reader.readAsDataURL(file);

reader.onloadend = function(e) {
    var image = $('<img>').attr('src',e.target.result);
    $(image).appendTo.('.user-logo');
}
```